# div sits outside flex container, causing text cutoff

Tags: css, flexbox

[This JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/berrw9h3/) is a rough representation of my code. I have included all CSS styles that I believe could be affecting the problem. Some of these are required for my responsive design, so I need to work out what style is causing the issue in order to find a workaround.

As you can see, my `.text` div (in green) is sitting outside the bounds of it's container `article` (in yellow). On my actual project, this is causing the text to be cut off. In my JS example, it's simply extending `.text` beyond the edge of its container, `main`

The layout uses flexbox. The basic idea is that `.image` and `.text` both sit at 50% width, so they sit next to each other, and `.text` has a `24px` margin to the left so there is a neat gap in between them.

Why is `.text` sitting outside of its bounding container?

```
article {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 24px;

  > * {
    flex 0 0 50%;
  }
}

.image {
  flex: 1 0;
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

.text {
  flex: 1 0;
  margin-left: 24px;
  width: calc(50% - 24px);
}
```

Comment: is this what you try to do ? https://jsfiddle.net/berrw9h3/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below:

```
article {
  display: flex;
  width: calc(100% - 24px);
  margin-left: 24px;
  background-color: yellow;
 }
```

You can see it working in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/berrw9h3/4/).

Comment: Hi there, that margin is required, as I need a left margin on the whole `article` to divide up this content from elsewhere. Can you explain why this is causing an issue, and a possible workaround, rather than just removing something I need?

Comment: because of div always take 100% width so its no need and if you really need of width then please decries your margin into width.

Answer (score 0):

```
article {
  display: flex;
  /* width: 100%; remove this line */
  margin-left: 24px; 
  background-color: yellow;
 }
```

having the width of the box be 100% of the parent, whilst also having a margin is what was causing the overflow. Try it out!

Comment: Thanks for hunting down the issue. So I'm not stuck because my code does require that to be set as a width (on my actual code it's set as 60% - 24px) because there are other elements inside `main` which I did not include here in my example. I'm going to try box-sizing:border-box plus padding instead of margin and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Francesca you can change your the `width` of your `article` element to:

```
  width: calc(100% - 24px);
```

That means 100% of the screen minus your desired margin. Having it at 100% causes its actual `width` to be `100% + 24px` and therefore cuts it to fit to the`width` of the screen.

Check an updated jsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/berrw9h3/5/).